# Reading more than 20 bytes in android BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android App in which I need to use data from BLE device (unfortunately I cannot manage the device). The peripheral is sending data containing 34-40 bytes. The problem is that after reading the Characteristics, I only receive last 20 bytes (btw the last few are just somehow zeros 0x00 - but they shouldn't be zeros). The beginning of characteristic dissapears. Even after requesting higher MTU it didn't work (probably cause of the BLE perpihperal doesn't support bigger MTU). I have also tried every single app on Play Store and all of them give exact score as mine app - just 20 bytes.

I guess I have read all subjects regarding BLE reading Characteristics, unfortunately noone of solutions I've found made the code work. Have anyone faced this problem and found any solution to this?

Comment: I can't believe that "20 bytes" is a limitation of BLE.  I'm sure it's either 1) your code, and/or 2) some peculiarity with the particular BT device.  Q: Can you show us any code?  Q: What BT device are you using?  Q: Have to tried reading from *OTHER* BT devices?  SUGGESTION: See if this article helps: http://nilhcem.com/android-things/bluetooth-low-energy

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of the BLE app or the Android OS itself, but rather a limitation of the peripheral itself. When BLE came out in 2010 in Bluetooth v4.0, it was mostly aimed at sensors and applications with low bandwidth. This is why 20 bytes to read heart rate/temperature/blood pressure etc. seemed fine at the time. Since then BLE has evolved to support large data transfer (e.g. with Bluetooth v4.2, you can send packets up to 251 bytes instead of 27 bytes. With Bluetooth v5.0, you can send packets on the 2MPHY bandwidth instead of the 1MPHY). However, peripherals that supported the old version of Bluetooth are still stuck with the relatively low throughput.

Have a look at the links below that might help you with your problem or give you more of an explanation on the possible causes:-

- [Maximizing BLE throughput on iOS and Android](https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/)
- [Understanding BLE throughput on Android](https://xizzhu.me/post/2021-08-06-android-ble-throughput/)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [A practical guide to BLE throughput](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/ble-throughput-primer)

Answer (score 1):

If you have negotiated a larger MTU which has succeeded, but notifications from the device still only contain at most 20 bytes, then there is nothing "wrong" with your app and neither BLE itself. Instead the application running on the peripheral has decided to just send 20 bytes per notification, even though every possible layer / part tolerates larger notifications. It's unclear from your question if MTU negotiation failed, or despite successful MTU negotiation, you didn't get larger notifications.